# Is sparse matrix-vector multiplication available in Simulink/xPC?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, simulink, xpc-target

I am trying to make my control algorithm more efficient since my matrices are sparse.  Currently, I am doing conventional matrix-vector multiplications in Simulink/xPC for a real-time application.  I can not find a way to convert the matrix to a sparse one and perform that type of multiplication where it is compatible with xPC.  Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears, at least as of earlier this year, that it is impossible to do sparse matrices in Simulink: see [this Q&A on MathWorks' site](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/9261-sparse-matrices-in-simulink).  As the answerer is a Simulink software engineer, it seems authoritative.  :)